# Is there a way to view data stored using httpcontext.current.cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, distributed-caching

I am using httpcontext.current.cache to store data in-memory for my ASP.NET application. 
1. I just want to monitor what data is captured on Cache and how much memory used. Can I view this using IIS or any tools available?
2. Is the data stored on Web servers hard disk or RAM?
3. If I have multiple worker process, how can I distribute the cached data?

Comment: I would suggest using a profiler to measure things in your app. [How to: Profile a Web Site or Web Application Using the Performance Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx)

Comment: Regarding your question on distributing the cached data:I personally do not agree with this wish.Think about it like so:A cache is an enhancement of a pipeline which accelerates fetch results,most particularly, the ones which occur most often.If by multiple worker processes you mean to say that your app is deployed on a cluster,then think about user affinity and the fact that each node should be allowed to treat it's loyal users in a more distinctive way.Each application node's cache should reflect the habits of that node's users.Load balancers can keep source ip-node relationships for a while